# Client-Server Application with Plug-in Architecture

Tags: .net, winforms, wcf, plugins, client-server

I am thinking about a plugin model for my client-server application.  A plugin will have a UI part(for configuration, runs on client) and an execution part(does the work, runs on server).  For simplicity, I'm trying to figure out if I can locate my plugin DLL on the server side, but still show the UI on the client side.

I thought about passing the Winforms Control object over WCF, but I'm not sure if this is possible.  All my plugins will derive from a base class, so at a minimum I'll have to set the serviceknowntype for each plugin at runtime.

I'm trying to avoid deploying the plugin DLL to both client and server machines and having logic to find and load all plugins in each location.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What about deploying the app with Click-Once?  Let it handle the deployment, then you don't need to worry about delivering the plugin dll through WCF (which has a funny code smell IMHO).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find a way to do this.  We are sticking with a copy of plug-in dll on both client and server.

Answer (score 0):

Developer of whole world advising to separate logic from presentation (thats what MVC pattern about). May be worth thinking about automatic update of client.